# XML web service running on Ubuntu

Tags: web-services

VS Studio 2005

I have developed an application that will need to access a web service.

I will be developing the web service. However, the platform will be Ubuntu running Apache Tomcat server.

I have 2 questions:

1) Can I deploy a MS XML web service to run on a Ubuntu Server?

2) If I can't. I will have to develop a Java Web Service. However, my application that is written in VS C# 2005 will need to access it will be a windows application. How can my application access a Java Web Service?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want cross-platform compatibility, you can only deploy .net code that runs under Mono.  The best way to check this is to actually develop the code under Mono and use Mono to test it.  So, don't use Visual Studio.  Sorry.
2. There is no problem with interfacing pieces of code written in two different languages.  You can use XMLRPC, a RESTful API, or a proprietary protocol.  I'm sure there are other ways for the two to "talk", as well.